# Android webView dispatchKeyEvent doesnt work on Kitkat

Tags: android, webview, key, android-4.4-kitkat, dispatch

I am dispatching the user entered input into an Android **web-view** using the below approach:

```
            webView.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(System.currentTimeMillis(),
                String.valueOf(c), InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE));
```

This works fine on all Android devices with OS version upto 4.3 but doesn't work on 4.4 (Kitkat).

Has anything changed in OS version 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66715

Unfortunately, this issue is 9 months old and hasn't been touched... /rolleyes /facepalm